# How to select a specific range based on user input

Tags: microsoft-excel, worksheet-function, microsoft-excel-2010

In the attached image, I want to  sum up C2 to C14 in D column of sheet 1. This number '14' will be selected by user in other sheet, lets say in sheet 2, R4 cell. The next row in C column will be C3:C15 which should be automatically formed by dragging. How can I modify the command to do this?

I am elaborating my question below:
***Range will be user defined in Sheet 2, R4 cell. Based on this user defined range, how many values will be summed up in sheet 1-that will change. If R4 cell input is 10,  I want to do first sum in D2 cell sum(C2:C11) and in D3 cell-I want to do sum(C3:C12) etc. If user gives range 12 in R4 cell in sheet 2, I want to do sum in D2 cell(sheet 1) as sum(C2:C13), in D3 cell  sum(C3:C14) and so on...

[image]

Comment: What have you tried?

Comment: I have no idea how to do this

Comment: Hi, your question simply does not provide sufficient information that would allow a response. What are you actually trying to achieve?

Comment: @nyeas001,, the formula you have used =SUM(C2:C14) then fill down is the most easiest way to SUM set of every 14 rows . Another is the incremental SUM `=SUM(OFFSET(C3,COUNTA(C2:C15)-A$1,0,A$1,1))`  where A1 is cell has 14 !!

Comment: "Lets say in sheet 2, R4 cell." did you mean the range will change based on R4 cell value? Try to provide more information...

Comment: Yes @Lee, range will change according to R4 cell value

Comment: Note I corrected some relative/absolute referencing in my solution

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can do this in several ways, including SUMIFS or OFFSET. Using INDEX is non-volatile and fast:

```
=SUM(C2:INDEX($C2:$C$100,Sheet2!$R$4))
```

Think of INDEX as picking the i'th number or reference from an array. Using say `=INDEX($C$2:$C$100,2)` on its own in a cell, will simply return the value 13 from C3 (from your example). However INDEX is also one of a few functions that can also return a reference, so `=SUM($C$2:INDEX($C$2:$C$100,2))` becomes `=SUM($C$2:$C$3)`.

EDIT: Note the proper use of relative referencing in the range argument of INDEX. You want the start of the "indexed array" to move with formula as it gets dragged down, otherwise you will always pick the same indexed cell. However, when using the formula as is, Excel warned that the formula may be skipping adjacent values (which is what we intend to do), but I don't like those little green warning arrows. You can just ignore it without issue, but here is an alternative formula with absolute referencing and no warnings (though slightly more computationally intensive):

```
=SUM(C2:INDEX($C$2:$C$100,Sheet2!$R$4+ROW(C2)-1))
```

Answer (score 0):

An easy-to-understand possibility is to use additional columns (helper columns) to see if the value in each cell should be added up or not, and then add the values.

For instance:
[image: Example]

The "Sum" cell is the sum of the E column, which has "0" value for cells larger than the value in the "Range of" cell.